# keep getting internal server error with nest.js jwt

Tags: jwt, nestjs

I am using Nest.js JWT to protect my resources but i keep getting internal server error when i dont provide token or the token is invalid instead of get unauthorization exception as shown in the following jwt strategy file

```
import { Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from "@nestjs/common";
import { PassportStrategy } from "@nestjs/passport";
import { ExtractJwt, Strategy } from "passport-jwt";
import { AuthService } from "../services/auth.service";

export interface JwtPayload {
    user: string,
    refreshToken: boolean
}

@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
    constructor(
        private authService: AuthService
    ) {
        super({
            jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
            ignoreExpiration: false,
            secretOrKey: process.env.SECURITY_KEY,
        });
    }

    async validate(payload: JwtPayload) {

        // prevent passing refresh token as access token 
        if (payload.refreshToken) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException('Access Token Only');
        }

        const user = await this.authService.getUserFromJwtPayload(payload.user);

        if (!user) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException('Invalid User');
        }

        // checks if user logged out
        if (!user.refreshToken) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException('You have logged out');
        }

        return user;
    }
}
```

Please assist me i dont know why am keeping getting internal server error, is there any place missing or there is something i have to do.

Comment: i found the solution, i did not run the packages install ```npm install @nestjs/jwt @nestjs/passport @nestjs/passport-jwt passport passport-jwt``` after that it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you run the following command if you get internal server error `npm install @nestjs/jwt @nestjs/passport @nestjs/passport-jwt passport passport-jwt`

Answer (score 0):

I think something is going wrong in this process:

```
const user = await this.authService.getUserFromJwtPayload(payload.user);
```

So it does not get tot the part where you check if you have a valid user or refreshToken. I think that if you remove both if statements that you will still get the internal server error.

Comment: i found the solution, i did not run the packages install npm install @nestjs/jwt @nestjs/passport @nestjs/passport-jwt passport passport-jwt after that it worked